# Package level logging in python

Tags: python, logging, packaging

I am trying to set up package level logging via my **init**.py file.
I have been testing this in virtual environment but cannot seem to understand the error.
My package structure is as so:

```
extracts
    extracts
        __init__.py
        logconfig.ini
        methods.py
        foo.py
setup.py
requirements.txt
```

setup.py looks like so:

```
setup(name='extracts',
  version='0.0.1',
  description='Extracts',
  packages=['extracts'],
  package_data={'extracts': ['*.ini']},
  install_requires=requirements,
  zip_safe=False
  )
```

**init**.py is causing me problems.

```
logfile = resource_stream(__name__, 'logconfig.ini')
logging.config.fileConfig(logfile)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.info('Importing extracts 0.0.1')
```

foo.py is the script i'm trying to run. It import functions from module 'methods.py'. When that occurs, **init**.py should be triggered and set up logging for foo.py. Unfortunately everytime I try this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from extracts import methods
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/extracts/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    logfile = resource_stream(__name__, 'logconfig.ini')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 942, in resource_stream
    self, resource_name
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1346, in     get_resource_stream
    return BytesIO(self.get_resource_string(manager, resource_name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1349, in     get_resource_string
    return self._get(self._fn(self.module_path, resource_name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1425, in _get
    return self.loader.get_data(path)
IOError: [Errno 0] Error: 'extracts/logconfig.ini'
```

https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#basic-resource-access mentions that the package_or_requirement in resource_stream(package_or_requirement, resource_name) needs to be importable. 
But what I don't understand is that the extracts pacakge is importable since

```
from extracts import methods
```

does not fail. Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: moving the foo.py script one level higher (under /extracts/ rather than /extracts/extracts) works. I'm not sure why